# Much staff vs many staff

Tags: grammar

I was wondering which one of following sentences is the right way of asking:

> "How much staff do you have?"

> "How many staff do you have?"

Personally I would use "much", but depending on the translation of "staff" into my mother tongue it
can be argued wether it is countable or not. The word staff could be understood as either a single employee or the collective of all employees.

Answer (score 1):

Even *staff* as a collective is counted in individuals; the number of them isn't an infinitely variable quantity, like the amount of a substance, so I think you have to use *many.*

Comment: I have no idea why but this answer is correct in British english.